# Price filter is not working in catalog search in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, price, filter, catalogsearch

I am working on catalog search but on result page price filter in not working I have used following code on filter.phtml

```
<ol>

    <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>

        <li>

            <?php if (($_item->getCount() > 0) && (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'catalogsearch') === false)): ?>

            <a href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>"><?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?></a>

            <?php 



            elseif(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'catalogsearch') == true): //afegitó 

                $category = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')->addFieldToFilter('name', $_item->getLabel());

                $cat_det=$category->getData();

                $category_id=$cat_det[0][entity_id];



            ?>

            <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>&cat=<?php echo $category_id ?>"><?php echo $_item->getLabel() //afegitó ?></a>

            <?php else: echo $_item->getLabel() ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

            (<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)

        </li>

    <?php endforeach ?>

    </ol>
```

And result is showing like this
[image]

Please anyone provide me solution..